# What are syntactic structures?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, argument-structure

I was hoping you could help me clarify what the term *syntactic structure* refers to. I came across a question about which syntactic structures play a certain syntactic function (verb, object, etc.) in a sentence. What I first thought of was NP, VP, etc.

However, doing a little research on the internet, I came across the terms *structure of modification*, *structure of predication*, etc., which I have never heard of. Would anyone be able to tell me whether English syntactic structures refers to NP, VP, etc. or structure of modification, predication, etc.?

Comment: [Extremely related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_Structures).

Comment: Welcome to the site. To avoid confusion, I suggest that all acronyms (such as NP and VP) should  be defined on their first use. If you look at https://www.allacronyms.com/VP for example you will find a huge number of possible meanings.

Comment: _Structure_ is a word that gets a lot of use and has a lot of meanings in linguistics. Chomsky's first big hit was a small book called _Syntactic Structures_, and phonology, semantics, and pragmatics (not to mention socio-, psycho-, and historical linguistics) all make use of the term, in different ways. Syntactically, it refers to semi-fixed assortments of words and morphemes like [the _let alone_ construction.](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/~filip/fillmore+88.pdf).

Comment: @Anton As EL&U is a site for linguists and serious enthusiasts of English, VP, NP etc do not need further elucidation here.

Comment: @Araucaria If they are indeed serious they will recognize the need for good style, as I have suggested, to define acronyms for the avoidance of doubt. I would never accept a technical report or peer-reviewed article for publication without such care, so why try to debase this site by an esoteric and exclusive attitude that denies some readers understanding? The site is a good standard and is intended to promote usage to all, even if written by enthusiasts such as you: why argue for it to be sloppy and recondite?

Comment: @Anton VP, NP etc are conventional and understandable.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore I might agree with you were it easy for non linguists to search “VP” on the site (equivalent to providing readers with a glossary). Try that search and then consider the plight of the non-specialist who comes here for enlightenment. Why deny them the courtesy of a quick and costless definition?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't specific to English.